# Convergence of "mixed" series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider series

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}L_f^ip_i,
\end{align}

where $L_f\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (more precisely $L_f$ is Lipschitz constant) and $p_i$ is probability for $i\in\mathbb{N}_0$, so $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} p_i=1$.

Can we say something about convergence of this series in general?

Can we say something about convergence of this series  if we asssume that $L_f\in\left(0,1\right)$? So my first idea was that then the $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}L_f^i,$ is convergence geometric series and the series $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}L_f^ip_i$ was "mixed" from two convergence series. So in this case I expect some "nice behavior" of this series.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$0\leq p_i \leq 1$ so $L_f \in (0,1)$ is enough. Also, $L_f =1$ is fine t00.  But there are examples where the series diverges whenever $L_f >1$. Example: $p_i=\frac  6 {\pi^{2}} \frac 1 {i^{2}}$. Apply Ratio test to prove divergence in this case.